# Quartz.net - fire trigger in custom time

Tags: c#, .net, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I have array of datetimes(about 5000 elements) and want to execute a job on each of these datetimes.
Datetimes in array are custom ones, not periodical, so I cannot use CronTrigger and others.
Is there a simple way to create a trigger which will fire on given times?
Yes, I know that I can to start a new simple trigger(with one fire time, no repeation) each time after my job finished, but this way is not convenient for me.

Comment: Please be sure to include at least one language tag on your questions to help make sure your question is found by those that can best help you. Also be sure to read the tag descriptions, the quartz tag is depreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own trigger and use it to execute your job. If you're using v1.0 then you'll have to create a class that extends Trigger. Take a look at the [docs](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/1.0/html/topic644.html) for more details. If you're running v2.0 then you want to extend [AbstractTrigger](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/2.0/html/topic2076.html).

Comment: Greate, I've asked for **simple** way to do this. Making my own trigger is not a simple way :(

Comment: Take a look at `SimpleTriggerImpl.cs` in the source. It's really not that bad.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the datetime for trigger.The simple trigger which will fire n times from your customize time

```
public class JobScheduler
    {
       public static void Start()
       {
            ISchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
            IScheduler sched = sf.GetScheduler();
            DateTime[] Jobtime = new DateTime[5]; //Array Have Job time
            startDate[0] = new DateTime(2015, 6, 3, 16, 57, 0);
            startDate[1] = new DateTime(2015, 6, 3, 16, 59, 0);
            startDate[2] = new DateTime(2015, 6, 3, 17, 1, 0);
            startDate[3] = new DateTime(2015, 6, 3, 17, 4, 0);

            for (int i = 1; i < Jobtime.Count(); i++)
        {

            sched.Start();


            string strjob = "job" + i.ToString();
            string strgroup = "group" + i.ToString();
            string strtigger = "trigger" + i.ToString();

            IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<EmailJob>()
                .WithIdentity(strjob, strgroup)
                .Build();
            ISimpleTrigger trigger = (ISimpleTrigger)TriggerBuilder.Create()

                .WithIdentity(strtigger, strgroup)
                .StartAt(Jobtime[i])

                .Build();

            sched.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);

        }

       }
    }
```